# What become of the allocated pages after killing process without free page?

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

All.

Let's suppose that process'A allocate a lot of pages by such as below code.
And process'A periodically executes this code so it happens memory leak.

```
 // allocates 1Mb
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  page_p=alloc_pages(gfp_mask, 8);
}
```

BTW, what become of the allocated pages after killing process without free page?
Allocated pages are permanently leak?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you have virtual memory, which is a per process memory map. The processes memory is allocated from this map, and the OS maps this memory into physical memory, either RAM or swap.

When a process exits, the OS removes the processes memory map, and another process can reuse it. So leaked memory is only leaked when the process is running.

Comment: I think, your comment that leaked memory is only leaked when the process is running is only limited to process memory. Above test code try to allocate memory from buddy. This allocated memory will remain as leaked memory before free_pages function is called.

Comment: I think, in case of above test code, allocated pages will remain as permanent leak.

Comment: If you use `alloc_pages` in kernel space (as it is intended), then yes, you can create permanent memory leaks. But you cannot do that in userspace, as memory is only allocated through the virtual memory subsystem. If you are doing weird stuff with allocating kernel memory, and passing it to a process in userspace, then please stop.